# unable to update dynamic multiple records in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i'm trying to update multiple records using `$this->db->update()` while updating the record it's only updating the very first record of table..
there is my modal

```
public function SaveUpdate($data, $totalRecord)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $totalRecord; $i++) {

        $id = implode(", ", $data['id']);
        $DeptId = implode(", ", $data['defaultdeptid']);
        $chktme = implode(", ", $data['checktime']);

        //echo $chktme. " and id is " .$id;
        //die();

        $this->db->set('checktime', $data['checktime'][$i]);
        $this->db->where('ci.id', $data['id'][$i]);

        return $this->db->update('checkinout as ci');
    }
}
```

where `$totalRecord` is number of times loop will execute according to records and `$data` contains the id, deptid and checktime.. one more thing that when i echo checktime and id it displays id and checktime of all records..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It updates only the first record because you are using `return`.
SO to fix that, delete that `return`!

```
public function SaveUpdate($data, $totalRecord)
{
 $myReturn = "Update Succeeded";
 for ($i = 0; $i < $totalRecord; $i++) {

    //$id = implode(", ", $data['id']); //You dont need this
    //$DeptId = implode(", ", $data['defaultdeptid']); //You dont need this
    //$chktme = implode(", ", $data['checktime']); //You dont need this

    //echo $chktme. " and id is " .$id;
    //die();

    $this->db->set('checktime', $data['checktime'][$i]);
    $this->db->where('ci.id', $data['id'][$i]);

    $this->db->update('checkinout as ci');
    if(!($this->db->affected_rows())){
       $myReturn = "Unable to update ".$data['checktime'][$i];
       return $myReturn;
    }
 }
 return $myReturn;
}
```

Comment: @SarmadSoomro, I've updated the answer, now your function will return a message of success or failure.

Comment: dear i've checked the datatype of `$this->db->update()` its returning as NULL and condition is not working accordingly in NULL type..

Comment: You are right! So, as far as I know, the best way to do this is by checking the number of the affected rows. I've edited the answer, hope it help!

Comment: Thanks man..! it's working fine now,, thumbs up for you bro Hamza Abdaoui

Comment: Don't make DB actions in loops. Use loop only to format array (or object) data. Make DB action outside the loop.